# Number is within 5% of another number

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a ruby script to compare two sets of numbers that should be within 5% of eachother.  Is there a slick way to evaluate this within ruby?

Something like

```
5.1.withinPercent(0.05) 5
```

Comment: I don't know of an existing method, but it's trivial to write one (if you want a method, that is. It doesn't need to be a method. Just include the logic in your loop.)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev agreed; just wanted to know if there's a cool one included in ruby

Comment: `0.05.tap { |e| break (5-e..5+e) === 5.1 }`

Comment: What you're describing is very similar to, for example, MiniTest's [assert_in_epsilon](https://apidock.com/ruby/MiniTest/Assertions/assert_in_epsilon) method. So if you want to perform this check *in the context of a test*, there's probably a method available for you already.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin `cover?` is more efficient since `===` uses `include?`

Comment: @CarySwoveland to be fair you could still put this in `Numeric` because while `Complex` does inherit from `Numeric` it undefines many of the `Numeric` methods that are not applicable to `Complex` numbers https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/complex.c#L2229

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just an idea, monkey patching the `Float` class:

```
module MyFloatPatch
  def within(percent: 0.0, of: 0.0)
    (self - of).abs <= of * percent / 100.0
  end
end

Float.include MyFloatPatch

5.25.within percent: 5, of: 5.0 #=> true
5.26.within percent: 5, of: 5.0 #=> false
```

Comment: It's nice to define this as a `module` since then it shows up in the ancestry chain and there's no mystery as to where that method came from.